# Php image rotate , как сохранить прозрачность?

Tags: php

Пробую так:

```
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng($img_finger);

$transColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($stamp, 0, 0, 0, 127);

$stamp = imagerotate($stamp,2,$transColor);

$im = imagecreatefrompng($img_source);

imagealphablending($stamp, true);
imagesavealpha($stamp, true);

imagealphablending($im, true);
imagesavealpha($im, true);

imagecopymerge($im, $stamp, $x, $y, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp), 100);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
```

Но изображение к которому применил imagerotate, всегда имеет непрозрачный фон, что не так с этим? все указал, ему все равно наплевать на прозрачность(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693585/background-transperancy-in-imagerotate не оно?

Comment: нет, это не помогает

Comment: Вы не делаете imagefill на $transColor после его аллокации - в примере от @splash58 это делается.